# Why apriori telling me attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, apriori, arules, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to do a market basket analysis using `arules` package. However, when I was using the `apriori` algorithm, `R` reported the following message.

```
dt <- split(deviceshowlist$prog_title, deviceshowlist$device_id)
dt2 <- as(dt,"transactions")
rules <- apriori(dt2, parameter = list(support = 0.01, confidence = 0.05, minlen=2))
```

> Apriori
>
> Parameter specification:
>
> Error in print.default(parameter) : attempt to apply non-function

I looked at my transaction data structure and the function of apriori. It seems that there's nothing wrong. Kindly hope that someone ran into the similar question before and could help me with it.

Thanks

The structure of my dt and dt2 are updated as follows

```
 > str(dt)
    List of 5388
    $ 000000006201   : chr [1:2] "Modern Family" "Criminal Minds"
    $ 0000000080ed   : chr [1:5] "Blindspot" "Supergirl" "The Simpsons" "The Big Bang Theory" ...
    $ 000000009c7b   : chr [1:9] "Criminal Minds" "The Big Bang Theory" "Life in Pieces" "Limitless" ...
    $ 000000009e56   : chr [1:7] "Friends" "2 Broke Girls" "Best Time Ever With Neil Patrick Harris" "Blindspot" ...

> str(dt2)
Formal class 'transactions' [package "arules"] with 3 slots
  ..@ data       :Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:25272] 10 21 5 21 27 30 35 0 8 10 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:5389] 0 2 7 16 23 24 32 39 40 50 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 37 5388
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..@ itemInfo   :'data.frame': 37 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ labels: chr [1:37] "2 Broke Girls" "Agent X" "Ash vs Evil Dead" "Benders" ...
  ..@ itemsetInfo:'data.frame': 5388 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ transactionID: chr [1:5388] "000000006201" "0000000080ed" "000000009c7b" "000000009e56" ...


     device_id     prog_title
1 0000000080ed      Blindspot
2 0000000080ed      Supergirl
3 000000009c7b Life in Pieces
4 000000009c7b      Limitless
5 000000009c7b       Quantico
6 000000009c7b     Code Black
7 000000009c7b    The Muppets
8 000000009c7b      Supergirl
```

Comment: Please add the output of str() function for your dt and dt2 datasets.

Comment: I can run your exact `apriori` statement without error on other data. But since we do not have your data, we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Katia Hi Katia, I've updated my data structure above.

Comment: @Derek. I think there is a problem with your original data. What are deviceshowlist$prog_title, deviceshowlist$device_id? Can you provide str() and summary() output on them. Is  deviceshowlist$device_id a factor? How many unique values do you have there? Is there anyway you can subset your data to some reasonable small example that results in error and you can provide here?

Comment: @Katia the prog_title is the name of each tv show, the device_id is like a unique transaction ID. My origin data is like two column, one column is  device_id and another column is prog_title. I first group them by device_id using the split function.

Comment: @Derek. Can you run str() and summary on your deviceshowlist dataframe. It looks like device_id is not a factor variable

Comment: @Katia I provided a sample data with only 8 rows and 2 unique device_id here. However, my code still doesn't work.

Comment: @Derek I think there is an issue with the versions of R/arules that you have installed. Try to update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ID column is a factor:

```
library(arules)

deviceshowlist <- data.frame(device_id = c("0000000080ed","0000000080ed",rep("000000009c7b",6)),
                             prog_title = c("Blindspot","Supergirl","Life in Pieces","Limitless",
"Quantico","Code Black","The Muppets","Supergirl"), stringsAsFactors=F)

deviceshowlist$device_id <- as.factor(deviceshowlist$device_id)

str(deviceshowlist)
#'data.frame':  8 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ device_id : Factor w/ 2 levels "0000000080ed",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
#  $ prog_title: chr  "Blindspot" "Supergirl" "Life in Pieces" "Limitless" ...


dt <- split(deviceshowlist$prog_title, deviceshowlist$device_id)
dt2 <- as(dt,"transactions")
rules <- apriori(dt2, parameter = list(support = 0.01, confidence = 0.05, minlen=2))

# Apriori
# 
# Parameter specification:
#   confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen
# 0.05    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5    0.01      2
# maxlen target   ext
# 10  rules FALSE
# 
# Algorithmic control:
#   filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
# 0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE
# 
# Absolute minimum support count: 0
# 
# set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
# set transactions ...[7 item(s), 2 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
# sorting and recoding items ... [7 item(s)] done [0.00s].
# creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
# checking subsets of size 1 2 3 4 5 6 done [0.00s].
# writing ... [188 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
# creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
```

Comment: Since the ID column values are supposed to be unique, they are always stored in transactions as character and not as a factor.

Comment: @MichaelHahsler If you are using split() function from the R base package, the second argument should be a factor. Please see ?split to read help for this function. Also your example dataset has non-unique values in the ID column.

Comment: I was referring to the way the transactionID is stored in the transaction object. The split in Derek's example worked because he (presumably) did not use stringsAsFactors=FALSE when he created the data.frame.